# Can't not activate middleware in RTK Query

Tags: reactjs, middleware, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I'm trying to connect middleware via an API so I assume that when I get a 401 error from my endpoints I'll be able to see my console.log, but that's not happening. I don't even see "middleware activated" Where am I wrong? My ultimate goal is to catch the 401 error and refresh the token. My endpoints are connected via injectEndpoints in separate files.

```
My store:

import { configureStore, getDefaultMiddleware } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import userReducer from "./user/slice";
import modelsReducer from "./models/slice";

//API
import { bplexApi } from "../api_v2";

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    user: userReducer,
    models: modelsReducer,
    //API
    [bplexApi.reducerPath]: bplexApi.reducer,
  },

  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => {
    return getDefaultMiddleware().concat(bplexApi.middleware);
  },
});

export default store;

My index.js:

export const bplexApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "bplexApi",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: "/api/v1",
    prepareHeaders: (headers) => {
      const token = getToken(); 
      if (token) {
        headers.set("Authorization", `Token ${token}`);
      }
      return headers;
    },
  }),
  endpoints: () => ({}),

  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => {
    console.log("middleware activated");
    return getDefaultMiddleware().concat({
      onError: async (error, dispatch, api) => {
        console.log("aaaa");
        const { status } = error;
        if (status === 401) {
          console.log("Error here");
          throw error;
        }
        throw error; 
      },
    });
  },
});
```

Comment: [`createApi`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/createApi#parameters) doesn't consume any `middleware` property. What are you wanting to accomplish? If you want to track response status codes you can create a custom [`baseQuery`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/customizing-queries#customizing-queries-with-basequery).

Comment: I'm getting a 401 error on my requests and want the middleware to work, I assumed I'd already enabled the middleware and would see at least console.log("middleware activated");

Comment: *That* "middleware" doesn't nothing as it's completely ignored by `createApi` since it's not a property it uses. Besides that, even if it did work, `getDefaultMiddleware` would expect to be passed middleware ***functions***, not objects with an `onError` property.

Comment: Are you trying to create a custom [middleware listener](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createListenerMiddleware#createlistenermiddleware-1)? It's not really clear what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: At some point the server may return 401 from the endpoints, and I wanted to create a middleware that caught this error and for example cleared the cookie and redirected to the login form

Comment: That's exactly what a [custom base query](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/customizing-queries#automatic-re-authorization-by-extending-fetchbasequery) can handle. In your case, instead of holding on to a request and refreshing a token, you can redirect to your auth page.

Comment: No, I don't believe so. Any middleware you create and add to the store won't have access to the query responses unless you customize the base query to dispatch an action for each and every one of them that is processed (*complete overkill IMP*).... and at this point you should just implement the behavior you want there in the custom base query function instead of also lassoing in other custom middleware and listeners.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers, it became more clear for me